# parseCSV php, CSV file with one line

Tags: php, csv

I use parseCSV to parse a CSV file: https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->auto($temp);
$csv->encoding('UTF-16', 'UTF-8');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($csv->data);
echo "</pre>";
```

where $temp is the file.

If my CSV file has more than one line everything works great:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 123
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 123
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 123
        )

)
```

But if the CSV file has only one line then it does not work:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123,123,123,123
        )

)
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: If the problem is constant (i.e. this is what happens by default 100% of the time), I am not familiar with this class library but perhaps it's just a bug or normal return for a 1-row csv. Either way, you should be able to just extend the class and revised the code to split a 1-row csv into the array like in your first example or do a post-process `if/else` when you process the array.

Comment: I think this is a bug in [`parsecsv.lib.php`](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php/blob/master/parsecsv.lib.php#L750): `($ch == $this->delimiter || $ch == "\n" || $ch == "\r" || $ch === false)` is the expression to match a line ending. Earlier, the method would just increase an internal `$strlen` variable if the last character is not `\n` or `\r`. However, an out-of-bound character will not be `=== false`, but rather `empty()` or `== false`.

Comment: PHP can handle CSV pretty well with SPLFileObject. Why do you need that library? http://php.budgegeria.de/fcysvyrbowrpgpfi